# vgdisplay not showing volume groups

Tags: 18.04

I want to extend my /

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           787M  1.9M  785M   1% /run
/dev/sda5       227G   65G  151G  30% /
tmpfs           3.9G  612M  3.3G  16% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      135M  135M     0 100% /snap/slack/20
/dev/loop2      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop0      2.0M  2.0M     0 100% /snap/serve/170
/dev/loop6       68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/77
/dev/loop3      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop4      451M  451M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/179
/dev/loop14      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8592
/dev/loop8      451M  451M     0 100% /snap/pycharm-professional/183
/dev/loop9      185M  185M     0 100% /snap/eclipse/40
/dev/loop10     728M  728M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/204
/dev/loop12      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop17      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/399
/dev/loop19      92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/8689
/dev/loop21     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98
/dev/loop26     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/postman/100
/dev/loop25     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/dev/loop22     161M  161M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop24     143M  143M     0 100% /snap/slack/21
/dev/loop16     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/postman/101
/dev/loop28      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop29     728M  728M     0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/198
/dev/loop15      45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop30     4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop13     164M  164M     0 100% /snap/spotify/41
/dev/loop18     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/97
/dev/loop23      68M   68M     0 100% /snap/sublime-text/85
/dev/loop7      182M  182M     0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop31      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1650
/dev/sda3       230G   90G  129G  42% /mnt/programming
/dev/loop32      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/495
/dev/loop33     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop34     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/135
/dev/loop11     4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/704
tmpfs           787M   40K  787M   1% /run/user/1001
```

i want to extend the size of /
but running these commands

```
sudo pvdisplay

sudo vgdisplay
```

displays nothing.

neither, `pvs` and `vgs` work.

so now i volume group and logical volumes are not display how do i extend the size of / ?

so why

Answer (score 1):

It appears, that you don't have any logical volumes on your system. Your root partition is a regular device (`/dev/sda5`).

Comment: so how can i extend my / ?

Comment: Unless there's unallocated space after your `dev/sda5`, you can't without re-partitioning your drive.

Comment: well if i have another disk let's say sdb then how do i extend / with the disk space from sdb ?

Comment: Again, you don't.
All you can do is moving some folders to a partition on `/dev/sdbX` and mounting them accordingly