# vgdisplay empty - No volume group shown after vgrename

Tags: boot, partitioning

Like asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217747/vgdisplay-not-showing-volume-groups), I have no output of `vgdisplay` in
Ubuntu 20.04. This is a direct result of renaming my volume group, as I was following this [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078061/707507). My recent history shows:

```
125 vgdisplay
126 vgrename 012345-6789-abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop-qrstuv LVM2_member_host
127 modprobe dm-mod
128 vgchange -ay
129 lvscan
130 mount /dev/sda2 /media/bo/backup/
```

Now there is no result of `vgdisplay`. I want to make sure before I shutdown the computer:

- Can I still reboot my machine now? How can I verify that?
- Will a newly created Ubuntu USB boot stick appear in the boot selection? (I want to install a newer OS now.)

Comment: @guiverc I removed the remark about the commenting. So just my question remains. Still wondering what makes it a bad question so that one person downvoted it.

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted sorry (*but I regularly can't predict*).  You mention Ubuntu but not what product/release is all I can see.

Comment: Appearantly, there was no way to verify that the reboot would work. I just tried it, and it worked. My second question about the appearance of the USB boot stick is kind of nonsens, as the boot menu is processed before the grub menu. I was mixing it up in total confusion. Sorry for that. The installation of a newer Ubuntu worked seemlessly.

Comment: Glad your situation resolved itself & you go there in the end.